# 503 proxy error and unable to establish SSL connection

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, reverse-proxy

I have a docker container running on my server. It's running an instance of collabora/code if that matters. I have a external subdomain that does a reverse proxy to the container URL but getting a 503. Digging a little deeper, it seems I'm getting a `Unable to establish SSL connection` error. I'm running out of things to check on my own, hoping someone can advise...

```
$ wget -O - https://office.mydomain.com/hosting/discovery > /dev/null 
--2019-01-15 22:40:29--  https://office.mydomain.com/hosting/discovery
Resolving office.mydomain.com (office.mydomain.com)... 5.28.62.38
Connecting to office.mydomain.com (office.mydomain.com)|5.28.62.38|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 502 Proxy Error
2019-01-15 22:40:31 ERROR 502: Proxy Error.
```

So proxy error. Now I’m looking at the virtual host file, I can see where it’s trying to reverse proxy to:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName office.mydomain.com:443

# SSL configuration, you may want to take the easy route instead and use Lets Encrypt!
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/office.mydomain.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/office.mydomain.com/chain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/office.mydomain.com/privkey.pem

SSLProtocol             all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!DSS
SSLHonorCipherOrder     on

# Encoded slashes need to be allowed
AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode

# Container uses a unique non-signed certificate
SSLProxyEngine On
SSLProxyVerify None
SSLProxyCheckPeerCN Off
SSLProxyCheckPeerName Off

# keep the host
ProxyPreserveHost On

# static html, js, images, etc. served from loolwsd
# loleaflet is the client part of LibreOffice Online
ProxyPass           /loleaflet https://127.0.0.1:9980/loleaflet retry=0
ProxyPassReverse    /loleaflet https://127.0.0.1:9980/loleaflet

# WOPI discovery URL
ProxyPass           /hosting/discovery https://127.0.0.1:9980/hosting/discovery retry=0
ProxyPassReverse    /hosting/discovery https://127.0.0.1:9980/hosting/discovery

# Main websocket
ProxyPassMatch "/lool/(.*)/ws$" wss://127.0.0.1:9980/lool/$1/ws nocanon

# Admin Console websocket
ProxyPass   /lool/adminws wss://127.0.0.1:9980/lool/adminws

# Download as, Fullscreen presentation and Image upload operations
ProxyPass           /lool https://127.0.0.1:9980/lool
ProxyPassReverse    /lool https://127.0.0.1:9980/lool
</VirtualHost>
```

So (SSH into that server to run locally) I’m trying to send a request to the reverse proxy destination, cutting out the proxy:

```
$ wget -O - https://127.0.0.1:9980/hosting/discovery > /dev/null 
--2019-01-15 22:20:25--  https://127.0.0.1:9980/hosting/discovery
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:9980... connected.
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

So there is a problem with my SSL connection? The keys do exist and I’ve used Let’s encrypt for this and other sites that work fine over HTTPS.

More info if it helps:

```
$ sudo netstat -lnpt
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State   

    PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      15179/mysqld
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6379          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      29677/redis-server
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      19278/sshd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      29538/master
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9980          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      27082/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      1011/apache2
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      19278/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::25                   :::*                    LISTEN      29538/master
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      1011/apache2

$ sudo docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                      NAMES
c714e3b8883d        collabora/code      "/bin/sh -c 'bash st…"   24 hours ago        Up 2 minutes        127.0.0.1:9980->9980/tcp   vibrant_haibt
```

Is there anything I might have done wrong in my virtual host setup? Anything else I ought to be checking? UFW, etc?

UPDATE

Curl with HTTPS:

```
$ curl -v https://127.0.0.1:9980/hosting/discovery
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 9980 (#0)
* found 148 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
* found 599 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* gnutls_handshake() failed: The TLS connection was non-properly terminated.
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) gnutls_handshake() failed: The TLS connection was non-properly terminated.
```

And without:

```
$ curl -v http://127.0.0.1:9980/hosting/discovery
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 9980 (#0)
> GET /hosting/discovery HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1:9980
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Empty reply from server
* Connection #0 to host 127.0.0.1 left intact
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

Comment: `tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      7489/apache2` looks a bit weird - you have an `apache` that is only listening for ipv6 connections on port 80? `docker-proxy` is the thing listening on `9880`...

Comment: It's also listening on 443, I've updated the full output. Sorry I was trying to keep it short, but didn't realise I'd cut another port Apache was listening to.

Answer (score 0):

It's seems that the docker container does not listen for HTTPS connection. Try switching the proxy configs to http and see if you are going to get a response.

Also you can verify locally if you do curl to the docker container over HTTP.
*Edit:

Can you provide out put of curl verbose output to the docker instance?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the response. I've updated my question now with curl response, please check.